# Azure functions and ASP.NET membership

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-membership, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that cleans a database of inactive users. This cleanup involves deletion of ASPNET Membership entries, by using:

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.DeleteUser(username);
```

The problem is that the ASPNET Membership framework expects the connection string in a app.config/connection.config file (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx).

I have added an app.config file with the necessary information to my Azure function but this did not work. I get the next error:

> System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: 'The connection name >'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the >connection string is empty.'

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So according to Microsoft's documentation on Azure Functions "A function app hosts the execution of your functions in Azure. It is a best practice to store connection strings and other secrets in your function app settings."

You can look at the sample below that implements something very similar to what you are doing.

The connection string is added in the Azure Portal by going to Azure Function App and selecting **Platform Features** then  **Application settings** and adding the entry to the **Connection Strings** section.

[Azure Function App example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup)

Comment: Of course, in production I would add the connection string in the place that you mention. But first I want to test it locally, for which case I need to specify the connection string in some file. The second problem is that, from what I see so far, ASPNET Membership requires this app.settings, which is simply not available for the function.